# What does Qt do if an error occurs in a constructor?

Tags: c++, qt

It is generally recommended to raise an exception if an error occurs in the constructor of a class.

In Qt, none of the classes throw an exception (as far as I know).

How does Qt handle errors that occur in constructors?

Comment: Read the following: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/exceptionsafety.html, http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qexception.html

Comment: Thanks for the links. However, they just answer my first question. What about errors in constructors?

Comment: That is the problem when a question is asked incorrectly, in SO a question is asked per post, so the button used to create it says **Ask Question**, it does not say **Ask Questions**, reads [ask] and improves your question

Comment: Thanks. I'll update my question.

Comment: Try not to put things in constructors that might fail.  Implement [exception safe constructors](http://www.stroustrup.com/except.pdf).

Comment: Qt constructors may either throw `std::bad_alloc` on failed allocation, or will print error message in `stderr` and leave object in uninitialized (default-constructed) state.

Comment: @AndreiR. why on StackOverflow-Qt it's so popular to answer in comments?

Comment: @Velkan possible, because there are a lot of newbie questions where comment is enought (instead of full well-formated answer). For example, this question is not related to Qt at all, it's about C++ basics.

Comment: @AndreiR. the part of `new QThing()` that may throw `std::bad_alloc` is the global `operator new`, not the `QThing::Qthing()`. The constructor is the latter.

Comment: @Caleth, `QThing::QThing(args...)` may allocate extra memory internally - most Qt classes use pimpl, some may need extra memory to store data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said Qt does not use exceptions, building a `QObject` will not *fail* on the Qt side (still the C++ memory allocation could fail).

What kind of error in constructor do you have in mind?
Qt will create object with an *invalid* state if necessary, in my opinion it is not a constructor error that should cancel the object creation but more of a *not-fully-initialized-yet-to-work-well* object-state.

Examples:

```
QRegExp regex1; // isValid() : false
QRegExp regex2("nop{"); // isValid() : false
// regex2.errorString() => "bad repetition syntax"

QSqlDatabase db; // isValid() : false

QDate date1; // isValid() : false
QDate date2(0, 0, 0); // isValid() : false
QDate date3(-1, 0, 1024); // isValid() : false

QString str1; // isNull() : true, isEmpty() : true
QString str2(""); // isNull() : false, isEmpty() : true
```

Comment: The kind of error in my mind can be opening a file. Think about a class which requires using a file for some operations. If the file cannot be opened, there is no use of creating an object of this class. And thanks for the answer. As I understand from your answer: Qt just sets a variable to inform that this object is not valid.

Comment: Yes exactly, there is an advantage to this : you can return objects (even if the creation failed) instead of error code and then check their valid state, you can also use them in a container that needs default constructor etc. Even if the object cannot be used, having the invalid object can be useful for coding simplicity.